# d3 stacked bar chart - data reformat required

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
JSONData = [
{ "Region": "NA", "Engagment": "Full"},
{ "Region": "NA", "Engagment": "Partial"},
{ "Region": "NA", "Engagment": "Full"},
{ "Region": "NA", "Engagment": "Partial"},
{ "Region": "LA", "Engagment": "Full"},
{ "Region": "LA", "Engagment": "Partial"},
{ "Region": "LA", "Engagment": "Full"},
{ "Region": "LA", "Engagment": "Partial"}
```

]

I'd like to use the above data set to build out a d3 stacked bar chart based using the Regions as labels and then total the Engagement values based on the sum of their unique values.  I was able to use the _groupBy method in underderscore.js to group the regions but am stuck trying to format the data so that it looks like:

Region Full Partial
 NA      2    2
 LA      2    2

I'm testing the code in the following jsfiddle library. http://jsfiddle.net/jkeohan/kvg9g5z7/

Any suggestions of reformatting the data to provide d3 numerical values instead of text?

Much appreciated..

Comment: `d3.nest()` will do the group, [as seen here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4679202), and it has a `rollup()` function for adding up values. [Eg here](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/)

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed...thanks so much...I should have guessed that d3 provided such functionality....